# Tool to determine what technology a website is built on

Tags: software-recommendation, websites

I know there are builtwith and wappalyzer. But they ask for a subscription for more details. Is there any GUI or terminal app to see the entire stack from front to backend of a website?

Answer (score 0):

No, If a Website is well build, it should be impossible to see, from the internet, what it is build on.

If (bad) people can guess or see your software stack, they also have easier access to eventual security holes or back doors.

Comment: _“If (bad) people can guess or see your software stack…”_ This implies [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). What about open-source websites like Wikipedia? So instead of _“if a website is built well”_ I would say: _if the author wants to hide the information_. However, this still does not necessarily mean that an application cannot guess.